# Independence of connectives in intuitionistic logic

Tags: logic, intuitionistic-logic

Consider the intuitionistic propositional logic with $\neg, \vee, \land, \to$ as primitive connectives. My question is, can any three of these connectives be used to define the remaining one? So, I am asking for four proofs that the remaining connective can or can't be defined in terms of the other three.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No three intuitionistic connectives can be used to define the fourth one. McKinsey [1] showed this using nigh-trivial semantic proofs: in modern terminology, we would say that he constructs Heyting algebras as counterexamples. Despite its age, the article remains very readable, and answers your question thoroughly.

Here I'll present some proof-theoretic arguments which make use of cut-elimination, and show that in particular disjunction and negation are independent of the other connectives. Unlike semantic proofs, these generalize straightforwardly to the first-order case (in fact, note that the independence of the quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$ follows from my answer to [your previous, related  question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3924936/in-intuitionistic-first-order-logic-can-the-nothing-quantifier-define-either/3927985#3927985)). For the other two connectives (conjunction, implication) I present a variant of McKinsey's proofs: while the independence of conjunction and implication can be shown proof-theoretically as well, the methods I know require quite a bit of symbol-pushing.

---

We will use the following property of the intuitionistic propositional calculus, which you can prove by induction on (cut-free) derivations (see also [2], Theorem 4.2.4).

- **Disjunction property**: if $\Gamma$ of does not contain any disjunction connectives, and $\Gamma \vdash M \vee N$, then we can find a proof of either $\Gamma \vdash M$ or $\Gamma \vdash N$.

**I.** Disjunction $\vee$ is independent of the other connectives $\neg, \rightarrow, \wedge$:

Suppose that we can find a formula $Q$ in the the $\{\neg, \rightarrow, \wedge\}$ fragment such that $Q \vdash M \vee N$ and $M \vee N \vdash Q$ holds for the atomic propositions $M,N$.

Since $Q \vdash M \vee N$ and $Q$ does not contain disjunctions, we have either $Q\vdash M$ or $Q\vdash N$ by the *disjunction property*.

But of course the same fails for $M \vee N$: neither $M \vee N \vdash M$ nor $M \vee N \vdash N$ are provable for atomic $M,N$. (Why? Cut $M \vee N \vdash M$ against the usual proof of $N \vdash M \vee N$ to obtain a proof of $N \vdash M$. By cut-elimination this would also have a cut-free proof, but that's impossible: what would be the last step?!)

Hence the supposed definition $Q$ cannot exist.

**II.** Negation $\neg$ is independent of the other connectives $\rightarrow, \vee, \wedge$:

The connectives $\{\rightarrow, \vee, \wedge\}$ build provable formulas from provable propositional atoms: if $\vdash A$ and $\vdash B$, then for any formula $Q$ made up of $A,B$ and the connectives $\{\rightarrow, \vee, \wedge\}$ we have $\vdash Q$. However, $\neg$ can be used to build unprovable formulae from provable atoms: if $\vdash A$ and $\vdash \neg A$ both hold, then we can extract a proof of $A \vdash$ (by looking at the last step of a cut-free proof of $\vdash \neg A$), so by cut we'd have a proof of the empty sequent $\vdash$. But that is impossible (what would be the last step of its cut-free proof?), so if $A$ is provable then $\neg A$ is not provable. Hence we cannot express $\neg$ in the $\{\rightarrow, \vee, \wedge\}$ fragment.

---

The set of numbers $\{1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36\}$ forms a [Heyting algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heyting_algebra) when equipped with the operations $\gcd$ (greatest common divisor, interpreting conjunction), $\mathrm{lcm}$ (least common multiple, interpreting disjunction), and the following implication operation $\Rightarrow$:

```
=>|  1  2  3  4  6  9 12 18 36
--+---------------------------
1 | 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36 36
2 |  9 36  9 36 36  9 36 36 36
3 |  4  4 36  4 36 36 36 36 36
4 |  9 18  9 36 18  9 36 18 36
6 |  1  4  9  4 36  9 36 36 36
9 |  4  4 12  4 12 36 12 36 36
12|  1  2  9  4 18  9 36 18 36
18|  1  4  3  4 12  9 12 36 36
36|  1  2  3  4  6  9 12 18 36
```

All you need to check is that if $z$ divides $x \Rightarrow y$ then $\gcd(z,x)$ divides $y$, and vice versa (admittedly, this is the tedious/annoying part of the semantic method, but you can cut this particular verification short using prime factors).

**III.** Conjunction $\wedge$ is independent of the other connectives $\neg, \vee, \rightarrow$.

The set $H = \{1,12,18,36\}$ is clearly closed under least common multiples. Referring to the table above, we can check that it is closed under $\Rightarrow$ as well. Since $1 \in H$, it follows that $H$ is closed under $\neg$ too. So, if conjunction was definable in the fragment $\{ \neg, \vee, \rightarrow \}$, then our set would be closed under greatest common divisors as well. But $\gcd(12,18) = 6 \not\in H$.

**IV.** Implication is independent of the other connectives $\neg, \vee, \wedge$.

Take the Heyting algebra above. Clearly the set $S = \{1,6,12,36\}$ is closed under both $\gcd$ and $\mathrm{lcm}$. Moreover, it is closed under negation, since $1 \Rightarrow 1 = 36$ and $x \Rightarrow 1 = 1$ for any $x > 1$ in $S$. So if implication was definable in the $\{ \neg, \vee, \wedge \}$ fragment, it would preserve membership in $S$. But $12 \Rightarrow 6 = 18 \not\in S$.

---

[1] J.C.C. McKinsey. Proof of the independence of the primitive symbols of Heyting’s calculus of propositions. The Journal of Symbolic Logic, 4(04), 155–158., 1939. [doi:10.2307/2268715](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2268715?seq=1)

[2] A. S. Troelstra, H. Schwichtenberg: Basic Proof Theory, 2nd edition, 2000. [ISBN 9781139168717](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/basic-proof-theory/928508F797214A017D245A1FB67CCCD9)

*edit* Simplified the wording of some of the arguments, added links and references

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. The only minimally functionally complete operator sets of intuitionistic logic are {¬, ↔, ∧} and {⊥, ↔, ∨}. But, since normally (A↔B) := (A→B)∧(B→A), you basically have to have them all.

For the second operator set, the minimally functional equivalencies are as follows:

$$¬A ↔ (A↔⊥)$$
$$(A∧B) ↔ (((A∨B)↔B)↔A)$$
$$(A→B) ↔ ((A∨B)↔B)$$

Comment: Do you have a reference for this minimality statement? And are {¬, ↔, ∧} or {⊥, ↔, ∧} or {⊥, ↔, →} not sufficient as well?

Comment: I don't see how you retain the disjunction property of intuitionistic logic without disjunction as a primitive, so probably not. But, it's not hard to test. Just pick your operators and work out intuitionistic identities with them.

Comment: How about the following definitions? In terms of {↔, ∧, ⊥}: p → q ≔ (p ∧ q) ↔ p, p ∨ q ≔ (p → q) ↔ q. In terms of {↔, →, ⊥}: p ∨ q ≔ (p → q) → q, p ∧ q ≔ (p → q) ↔ p.

Comment: You can't prove P∨Q intuitionistically from ((P∧Q)↔P)↔Q, because you can't prove either P or Q from it.